# Obtaining whether debug or release is being built in Visual Studio 2008 in WiX

Tags: wix

Is it possible to get hold of the flavour of the EXE file being built in the [Visual Studio 2008](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2008) environement?

Basically, I wish to do the following

```
<File Id="EventWatcher.exe" Name="EventWatcher.exe" KeyPath="yes" 
    DiskId="1" Source="..\EventWatcher\bin\$(sys.BUILDARCH)\EventWatcher.exe">
</File>
```

But instead of getting x86 for BUILDARCH I wish to get the word Release or Debug.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your WiX project is part of the same solution, you can use the following variable:

Usage:

```
var.<ProjectName>.Configuration
```

Example Usage:

```
$(var.MyProject.Configuration)
```

Sample values:

```
Debug or Release
```

Check *[Complete list of Candle preprocessor variables](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jrock/archive/2008/01/29/complete-list-of-candle-preprocessor-variables.aspx)* for other variables available and more details.